# Fan speed & temp

Tags: wubi, overheating, fan, temperature

When using Windows the fan speed and temp works fine, the fan run fast, and temp get higher only when playing a very high graphics games.

Now on ubuntu , i can hear the fan noise, and i can feel my laptop temp is very high.

I use ubuntu 12.04 lts, and i want the fan to work normally -speed up when it needed , but not full speed all time. I have install `lm-sensors`, but sill have the same problem. I hope that someone can help me.

Thanks.

Graphic card ATI/AMD
and no i didnt dectet bec he need root acess to deect

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Thames XT/GL [Radeon HD 7600M Series]

I use a Dell Inspiron 5520, 6G RAM.

Comment: if you have dual graphics card like nvidia optimus. This can happen, to pin point whether this is the issue please edit your question and include result of `lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: Did `lm-sensors` detect the fan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be different reasons that make the temperature high / fans working all the time on ubuntu.

Let's begin with graphics. Some video drivers don't have a correct management of power saving. I see you have a Radeon HD 7600M Series, so you have the choice beteween the proprietary drivers (aka fglrx) or the radeon open-source drivers. Normally, both should implement power saving correctly, but maybe if you use one of them you should try the other.

Now, the trip points. Those are the temperature points at which the fan begins to operate. Everything which is related to temperature in the system is in the folder `/proc/acpi/thermal_zone/TZ0`. Once you're in the directory (in a terminal), you can see the CPU temperature with the command `cat temperature` and also the trip points with `cat trip_points`. Here, you can see if there is a problem with your trip_points (if they're too high ..). You can change them, but be very careful, since a CPU without proper fan management overheats FAST.

A last thing could be a buggy BIOS. I had this problem on my Toshiba laptop, which is that the BIOS doesn't return the right power state and the system is not able to operate the fan correctly. I had to add this at the end of my grub boot command : `acpi.power_nocheck=1` (more explanations here : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2022147&page=2&p=12101889#post12101889 ). If you have a Toshiba Laptop, this is a common problem.

Hope this helps,

Ben

Comment: Thanks for replaying ben , but i am new on ubuntu os ,so most of ur answer i didn't understand.   iam using dell insprion 5520